# How to embed my groovy application in Java without groovy-all-2.5.6.jar?

Tags: groovy

With groovy 2.4.1 I'm used to integrate my groovy code in a Java application by adding the groovy-all-2.4.1.jar to the class path. When switching to groovy 2.5.6 I found in the doc that thanks to Java 9 the groovy-all-2.5.6.jar is no longer available at all. I found no doc how to embed groovy instead.

Answer (score 1):

The jar is still available; you can download it.

I assume what you *really* mean is that you can't get it from the Maven repo:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId> 
  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId> 
  <version>2.5.0</version> 
  <type>pom</type> 
</dependency>
```

Note the `<type>` element.

Comment: the single jar is not available in repository... it seems now it's combined from dependencies. http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.5.0/

Comment: I could not find the jar to download it. 
I'm not used to Maven, I'm still using pure ANT. Can I use the Maven POM to integrate the code somehow, to be able to distribute my application?

Comment: @axl https://groovy.apache.org/download.html But managing dependencies by hand is a *really* bad idea; hopefully you're at least using Ivy.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Looks like I have to change my project setup :-)